# Maximum call stack size error on button click in Next.js 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, callstack

I have a button that makes a call to `/api/reviews/react`. It does add an item for likes but upon refresh I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Call Stack
String.replace
<anonymous>
ec
/Users/ekrich/git/debug/commerce-karma-debug/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:255443)
eh
/Users/ekrich/git/debug/commerce-karma-debug/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (35:256105)
```

The following code has been reduced to the minimal.

## /api/reviews/react

```
import { Review, User } from "@/mongo";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import z from "zod";

export async function PATCH(request: Request) {
    const rawRequest = await request.json();

    const Schema = z.object({
        id: z.string(),
        like: z.boolean(),
        userId: z.string(),
    });

    const parsedRequest: RequestType = rawRequest.body;

    const valid = Schema.safeParse(parsedRequest);

    type RequestType = z.infer<typeof Schema>;

    if (!valid.success) {
        return NextResponse.json(
            { message: `Error: ${valid.error}` },
            { status: 400 }
        );
    }

    const review = await Review.findOne({ _id: parsedRequest.id });

    if (!review) {
        return NextResponse.json(
            { message: `Error: Review not found` },
            { status: 404 }
        );
    }

    const calculateLikes = (currentLikes: number, isLike: boolean) => {
        if (isLike) {
            return currentLikes + 1;
        }

        return currentLikes - 1;
    };

    const newLikeTotal = calculateLikes(review.likes, parsedRequest.like);
    await Review.updateOne({ _id: parsedRequest.id }, { likes: newLikeTotal });

    console.log(parsedRequest.id)
    await Review.updateOne(
        { _id: parsedRequest.id },
        { $push: { reactedBy: {_id: parsedRequest.userId, isLike: parsedRequest.like} } }
    );
    

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Successfully reacted" });
}
```

## FullReview.tsx (reactOnPost's parent component):

```
import { ReactOnPost } from "@/app/app/components";
import { User, Review } from "@/mongo";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default async function FullReview({ reviewData }: { reviewData: any }) {
    //const { title, stars, text, id,  createdAt, author } = reviewData;

    const id = "65418ba94eb5b488179fe7e7"
    const author = "64e15e9d29617fb0163de01b"

    const signedInUser = await currentUser()

    const signedInUserStore = await User.findOne ({userId: signedInUser?.id})

    const review = await Review.findOne ({author})

    console.log (review)

    return (
        <div className="full-review">
            <hr />
            <div className="actions">
            <ReactOnPost id={id} reactedBy={review.reactedBy} user={signedInUserStore._id}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

## ReactOnPost.tsx:

```
"use client"
import { thumbsUp } from "@/public/icons";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function ReactOnPost({id, reactedBy, user}: {id: string, reactedBy: string[], user: string}) {

  const hasReacted = (reactedBy: string[], user: string) => {
    let didReact = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < reactedBy.length; i++) {
        if (reactedBy[i] === user) {
          didReact = true;
          break;
        }
    }
    return didReact;
  }

  const reacted = hasReacted(reactedBy, user)

  if (reacted) {
    return <p>You already reacted. <button className="standard-clear-btn" style={{width: 50, height: 50, fontSize: "1rem"}}>Undo</button></p>
  }
  
    return (
        <div className="reactions">
            <Image src={thumbsUp} alt="Vote up" onClick={() => {
      fetch("/api/reviews/react", {
          method: "PATCH",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify ({body: {id: id, like: true, userId: user}})
        })
      }
      }/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm using Next.js 14. This error has occurred before I upgraded so it doesn't have anything to do with that.

## Update

I've found the line of code that may be the problem: `reactedBy={review.reactedBy}`. This on line 26 in `FullReviews.tsx`.